# Marker is not plotted on the map

Tags: api, google-apps

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" >
 <div id="map-canvas" style="min-height: 400px" ></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
     var lat, lon;
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                 function(position){
                 lat = position.coords.latitude;
                 lon = position.coords.longitude;
                 createMap(lat, lon)
                 } 
             )}  
     else
      {

                lat = 37.77493;
                lon = -122.419416;
                createMap(lat, lon)
      }

     }   
    function createMap(lat, lon) { 
    console.log(lat);        
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
        makeMarker(lat, lon)
  }

  function makeMarker(lat, lon) {
      var num = 1;
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

            position: myLatlng,

            title: 'Current Location',

           icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter_withshadow&chld='+num+'|FF0000|000000'

      });

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 

 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any more info, if you look in the developer console of the browser, do you see any errors or warnings?

First try adding a `</script>` element to the script tag where you are loading the google maps script from, some browsers may not like that to be missing.

Also maybe there is a https/http issue, try changing http://maps.google.com to use //maps.google.com (yes // without the http prefix) so it will just use whichever protocol (https or http) the page is running in.

Comment: I thought the </script> tag was missing too.  It's actually there.  You just have to scroll to the right more.  I don't think that VF would let the page save with it missing.

Answer (score 1):

Please give a try by changing http to https.

Comment: Thanks! I modified the code but now a marker won't show up on the screen with the current location. Can you take a look?

Comment: Why dont you use Javascript remoting to plot markers